# How to dual boot ubuntu with windows 8 in a laptop with earliar windows 7 in it?

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation

I am having Lenovo Ideapad Z570 which came with windows 7 home premium pre-installed with it.I have now removed windows 7 and installed windows 8 in it.But now when I am trying to install Ubuntu alongside,the GRUB menu isn't showing at startup.
I tried to install Ubuntu 12.04.3 and then 12.10.Once I did boot-repair also but after this,it ended up with grub-rescue.
Is there a way to install Ubuntu .Should I try with newer versions of ubuntu like 13.04?

Comment: did you installed ubuntu alongwith windows?Trying to install ubuntu means why do you run boot-repair?

Comment: Yes,I installed ubuntu alongwith windows 8.After installation,when I restarted,there was no grub menu,windows started automatically.I can't enter into ubuntu.So,i tried boot-repair from live-cd.

Comment: paste the boot-repair log in pastebin.com and then post the link here.

Comment: I am on windows 8 now and I again have to boot from live-cd for this and there is a risk of loosing windows 8 bootmgr again.Earlier when I tried boot-repair I had to reinstall windows 8.

Comment: boot ubuntu live usb/cd,click on try ubuntu then connect to the internet and install gparted by running `sudo apt-get update` `sudo apt-get install gparted` and upload it's screenshot to imgur.com.After that post the screenshot link here.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/pAwz4Uw.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change `UEFI mode` to `Legacy mode` in bios.After changing and save the changes, ran [*boot-repair*](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair).

Comment: I don't have UEFI mode in my bios.It comes with windows 8 laptop.My laptop had windows 7 pre-installed.

Comment: no legacy boot,then post the boot-repair log.Nothing to worry,your windows datas won't be gone.

Comment: there was lot of methods to make ubuntu to boot,plz keep in touch.

Comment: I need to do the recommended repair only??

Comment: yes,recommended repair only.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/G8Z4ct9.png

Comment: which partition to use for grub installation?

Comment: Install grub to /dev/Sda6

Comment: Click space bar to select partitions

Comment: I installed on dev/sda.It's telling that repair is successful and I can reboot now.Shall I do boot-repair again and install on /dev/sda6??

Comment: Did it works or not.

Comment: I have not restarted yet.I going to do it now and then come back to you.

Comment: Yes,it worked and now I am able to boot into ubuntu.Thank You so much for your help.

Comment: Can I upgrade to ubuntu 13.10 from ubuntu 12.10 from iso file???